# How do I ask multiple questions in python?

Tags: python, flowchart

I'm currently developing a very simple phone troubleshooting system with python which should include 10 possible outcomes. I have created the flowchart below to help me with the process but I'm still struggling with asking many questions which lead to another question etc.

Flowchart: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9kYvbwMV4pzczJoUUZLcW1mWmc/view?usp=sharing

Current python code:

```
print ('screen question1 here')
screen1 = raw_input('user answer')
if screen1 == 'yes':
    print('screen question2 here')
    screen2 = raw_input('user answer')
else:
    print('battery question1 here')

battery1 = raw_input('user answer')
if battery1 == 'yes':
    print('battery question2 here')
    battery2 = raw_input('user answer')
else:
    print('wifi question1 here')
    wifi1 = raw_input('user answer')

if screen2 == 'yes':
    print('screen question3 here')
    screen3 = raw_input('user answer')
else:
    print('camera question1 here')
    camera1 = raw_input('user answer')
```

Can someone lead me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: You question isn't clear. However, you might want to look into `elif` (you don't just have `if` and `else` at your disposal) and your `raw_input` prompts like `screen2 = raw_input('user answer')` could probably use some more descriptive text to understand what the user should be entering. You can also have "nested" `if`/`else` branches by increasing indentation based on the outcome of the first check.

Comment: Well the 'user answer' etc is just for now but I'll be adding in the questions more clearly once finished. But thank you. I'll be sure to look into elif now! @roganjosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just are not implementing the proper control flow in your file. If you want another question to occur depending upon a previous one, then you just encapsulate that question in that conditional.

```
print ('screen question1 here')
screen1 = raw_input('user answer')
if screen1 == 'yes':
    print('screen question2 here')
    screen2 = raw_input('user answer')
    if screen2 == 'yes':
        print('screen question3 here')
        screen3 = raw_input('user answer')
    else:
        print('camera question1 here')
        camera1 = raw_input('user answer')
else:
    print('battery question1 here')
    battery1 = raw_input('user answer')
    if battery1 == 'yes':
        print('battery question2 here')
        battery2 = raw_input('user answer')
    else:
        print('wifi question1 here')
        wifi1 = raw_input('user answer')
```

Looking quickly at the diagram you shared, this seems to be what you are looking for. The documentation for [More Control Flow Tools](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) provides nice documentation on this subject.